# How to use ForceReply in python-telegram-bot wrapper

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I've tried for quite a while, reading the python-telegram-bot wrapper API[python-telegram-bot wrapper](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot), telegram bot API, code snippets etc, but my lack of understanding(My programming knowledge is selective google copy-pastes) does not permit me to successfully implement the ForceReply option. ([ForceReply](http://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.forcereply.html#telegram-forcereply)

Basically what I'm trying is when a user types /sett the bot says "Enter No." and forces the user to reply to that message.

Sorry if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: See document of library

Comment: I have checked this documentation: https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ if that's what you mean. I'm not able to understand how to use telegram.ForceReply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Enter No.', reply_markup=ForceReply())
```

Comment: I've tried that, yet it does not make my telegram messenger quote the message("HI"). Below is the code I've tried: bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="HI", reply_markup=ForceReply())

Comment: Ok It seems there was conflicting code in my existing bot. Trying the above code in a fresh bot works absolutely fine. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def but(message):
    markup = types.ForceReply(selective=False)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Send me another word:", reply_markup=markup)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for contributing an answer. This would be more useful if it also included an explanation. Can you edit your answer to include that?

Answer (score -1):

For those who encounter this problem, this will solve it.

```
 markup = telebot.types.ForceReply()
 bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Enter No", reply_markup=markup)
```

Comment: Don't both other answers already say this? Please don't repeat answers.